# Why does it take so long for a Windows-Server 2016 machine to realise that a service has crashed and needs to be restarted?

Tags: crash, windows-server-2016, windows-services

I have installed a server application on a Windows-Server 2016 environment. During the last month, that application has crashed several times (for that matter, [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631939) has been created).

In the event log, an entry has been created every time the application crashes (so the Windows operating system is well aware of the fact that the application has crashed).
Nevertheless, this small table shows that it regularly takes quite some time for the operating system to restart the application:

```
Crash timestamp    Restart timestamp    Difference
          13:08                13:27    19 minutes
          14:03                14:09     6 minutes
          06:57                07:04     7 minutes
          16:06                16:36    30 minutes
```

Hereby the service definition:
Beware that the startup type has only very recently been modified from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" (this was done after all crash occurrences), so that should not be the problem.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can tell a Windows-Server 2016 system: *"If an application crashes, check your service definitions and in case the crashing application is defined as a service, start it up **immediately**!*".

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, but as a fail-safe, you could have a scheduled task that runs every x minutes to run `sc start servicename` from a batch file. If it's already running, nothing will happen. If it has stopped, it'll get started up again...

Comment: @spikey_richie: adding `sc start servicename` to the task scheduler, isn't that taking over the job of the operating system? :-) How come Windows-Server 2016 does not cover this? (Or is there a Windows-Server 2016 Windows update or patch which solves this and if so, which one?

Comment: I see somebody has voted to close this question, mentioning that more details should be added to this question. Which details would you like me to add to this question?

Comment: Yes, but it's a step you can take to mitigate until you have a proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the *Recovery* tab, as shown below, to see the settings for restarting a service after error. These can be changed to provide quicker restarts, to allow more attempts to restart, or even to run an application, such as one to send email to you that there is an ongoing problem with that service.

[image: Restarting a Service]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (I didn't know this existed). Thanks!